# Remove page link when equal to '#' in wp_nav_menu function - For a custom html sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to create a custom HTML sitemap using wp_nav_menu() because this function has the exact structure I want to display. It works, but the only problem I have is with some parent pages that are only used to display child pages. They have '#' as a link. So I want to display the title of these parent pages without the link.

This is the code I have so far. Maybe I'm completely wrong.

```
            <?php
        $webpages = wp_nav_menu( array(
            'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
            'menu'            => 'Menu principal',
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'pages-container',
            'post_status'     => 'publish'
        ) );

        if ( $webpages ) {

            $permalink = get_permalink();

            foreach ( $webpages as $page ) :
                setup_postdata( $page ); ?>
                <li> <?php
                if ($permalink === '#') {
                    echo strip_tags($permalink,'a');
                }
                else {
                    //'<a href="' . the_permalink(); . '">' . the_title(); '</a>';
                    $permalink;

                }
                ?> </li>

                <?php
            endforeach;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        ?>
```

Any help or advise is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: remove the `#` in the menus maybe? - you can do that after they have been created the first time.

Comment: also - your ` $permalink = get_permalink();` should be indside the loop as well - Else you are just checking the same link over and over.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both, but nothing changes.